# Does the Sentinel feat allow opportunity attacks against the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

The Sentinel feat (PHB, pg. 170) says:

> Creatures provoke opportunity attacks from you **even if they take the Disengage action** before leaving your reach.

The Mobile feat (PHB, pg. 168) says:

> When you make a melee attack against a creature, **you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature** for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

Effectively, Mobile lets you take the Disengage action for free if you make a melee attack, however it doesn't actually describe it as "Disengage", simply that you "don't provoke opportunity attacks". I will also point out that taking the Disengage action would allow you to avoid opportunity attacks from *all* creatures, whereas Mobile only lets you avoid opportunity attacks from *one* creature.

The Sentinel feat overrides the Disengage action and lets you make an opportunity attack anyway. But since the wording of the Mobile feat doesn't call it Disengage, whereas the wording of Sentinel does, I have a question:

Assume a PC that has the Mobile feat, who I'm just going to call "Mobile", and a PC with the Sentinel feat, who I'm calling "Sentinel". It's Mobile's turn, and Sentinel hasn't yet used their reaction.

**If Mobile ran up to and tried to hit Sentinel, then tried to run away, would Sentinel be able to make an opportunity attack against Mobile?**

Comment: Yup, that answers my question. I searched for a similar question beforehand, but found nothing, because the dupe doesn't mention Mobile specifically (except in a comment, which presumably the search function ignores).

Comment: I added the Mobile feat to the linked Question - thank you!